# Screen turns blank except the wallpaper then comes back

Tags: 16.04, unity, graphics, compiz

Facing an issue from yesterday. Whenever I open any application it turns blank except wallpaper. When it comes back appears with the application I started. Even when when I minimize any application the screen turns blank and comes back after a while. I can not shut down the pc too. When I click on it it turns blank. An Error sending message appears sometime. On detail I have seen it has something to do with 'COMPIZ'.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? I am having the same issue with the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and was going to ask the same question until I found this. If you don't know the version you have, go to Settings > Details. Underneath the logo it should say "ubuntu 16.04 LTS" or something like that.

Comment: I made a tag. It is 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Likely there is an issue with 16.04 LTS. I found a bug report on it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1663537

Comment: @karel Why say it is a duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: It's permissible to provide an additional link to alternative solutions that aren't included in the answers to the first link.

Answer (score 1):

This is [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594) (#1735594) that was reported December 1, 2017. Numerous bug reports have been filed, but marked as duplicates.

According to a comment on bug [#1741447](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447/comments/39), this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/) works, which many say fixed the issue. The main bug report also makes mention of this fix in reference to bug #1741447. Users can update their system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa` to their system's Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
```

This solution works for me, and is probably going to become the official fix, or will be incorporated into an update, if it hasn't already. More information can be found in the given links. Be sure to restart your computer after this is installed.

If you are affected, let them know by marking you are affected at the [main bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594).

Also make sure you keep up with all the latest updates, especially if you are uncertain about the above solution or if it did not work for you.